Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x00005555555554c6 in pop () очередь с приоритетом Си
Делаю задание по реализации очереди с приоритетом на си, с операциями вставки, извлечения первого элемента, элемента с заданным приоритетом и с приоритетом не ниже заданного.Приоритет задаётся числом от 1 до 255. С добавлением всё в порядке, но корректно извлекаются только первые 2 элемента, 3 извлекается, но затем при повторной попытке извлечения либо вывода содержимого происходит segmentation fault. Если при извлечении память не освобождать работает всё корректно. В чём ошибка?
queue.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "queue.h"

Queue* enqueue( Queue *head, int data, unsigned priority)
{
    Queue* buf = (Queue*)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    Queue* tmp;

    buf->data = data;
    buf->priority = priority;
    buf->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        buf->rear = buf;
        buf->front = buf;
        return buf;
    }
    tmp = head->front;

    if(head->front->priority > buf->priority)
    {
        buf->next = head->front;
        head->front = buf;
        return head;
    }

while(tmp->next != NULL)
{
    if(buf->priority < tmp->next->priority)
    {
        buf->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = buf;
        return head;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
}

head->rear = head->rear->next = buf;

return head;
}

int pop(Queue *head)
{
Queue *tmp;
int data;

if(head == NULL)
{
    printf("Queue empty!");
    return 0;
}

    tmp = head->front;
    data = tmp->data;
    head->front = head->front->next;
    free(tmp);

return data;
}

int pop_priority(Queue *head, unsigned priority)
{
Queue *tmp;
Queue *buf;
int data;

if(head == NULL)
{
    printf("Queue empty!");
    return 0;
}

tmp = head->front;

if(tmp->priority == priority)
{
    return pop(head);
    //head->front = head->front->next;
}
while(tmp->next != NULL)
{
    if(tmp->priority == priority)
    {
        data = tmp->next->data;
        buf = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
        //data = buf->data;
        free(buf);
        return data;
    }
    tmp = tmp->next;
}

if(tmp->next == NULL)
{
    printf("Wrong priority");
    return 0;
}
return 0;
}

int pop_under_priority(Queue *head, unsigned priority)
{
//Queue *tmp;
//int data;

if(head == NULL)
{
    printf("Queue empty!");
    return 0;
}
printf("Priority: %d\n", head->front->priority);

if(head->front->priority <= priority)
    return pop(head);

else
    printf("Wrong priority");

return 0;
}

void print_queue(Queue *head)
{
Queue* tmp = head->front;
if (NULL == head) 
{
    printf("List empty!\n");
    return;
}

do 
{
    printf("%d\n", tmp->data);
    tmp = tmp->next;
} while (tmp != NULL);

printf("\n");
}

queue.h
typedef struct Queue
{
unsigned priority;
int data;
struct Queue *front;
struct Queue *rear;
struct Queue *next;
}Queue;

Queue* enqueue( Queue *head, int x, unsigned priority);
int pop(Queue *front);
int pop_priority(Queue *head, unsigned priority);
int pop_under_priority(Queue *head, unsigned priority);
void print_queue(Queue *head);

main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "queue.h"

int main()
{
Queue *head = NULL;

head = enqueue(head, 100, 2);
head = enqueue(head, 8, 4);
head = enqueue(head, 4, 3);
head = enqueue(head, 3, 2);
head = enqueue(head, 6, 1);
head = enqueue(head, 17, 1);
head = enqueue(head, 13, 6);
head = enqueue(head, 55, 4);
head = enqueue(head, 90, 8);
head = enqueue(head, 102, 10);

print_queue(head);

printf("\n%d\n", pop(head));
printf("\n%d\n\n", pop(head));


print_queue(head);
printf("\n%d\n\n", pop(head));
printf("\n%d\n\n", pop(head));
}  


выяснил что у меня в один момент указатель head становится равен указателю head front, соответственно ячейка памяти в определённый момент стирается, когда пытаюсь его сдвинуть, опять возникает segmantation fault

Разобрался, стал хранить отдельно начало и конец, но как сделать очередь на основе двусвязного списка?
